# How to add hyperlink in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a hyperlink button in JSX. I tried researching how to do that. There are similar questions here but I don't know why my code is not working. I am using scrimba editor. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button = styled.button`
 background-color:  #e2e86f;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 `
 
 function SignUp(){
   <link href="https://google.com"/>
 }

 function SignIn(){
   alert('Signed In!')
 }

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={{color: "white"}}><center>Adope</center></h1>
      <h3 style={{color: "white"}}>Why Adope</h3>
      <ul>
      <li style= {{color: "white"}}>It is safe</li>
      <li style={{color: "white"}}>Gives you 2 weeks returning option</li>
      <li style={{color: "white"}}>Gives you a proper description of the product</li>
      <li style={{color: "white"}}>Has no software error</li>
      
      </ul>
      <center><h2 style={{color:"white"}}><center>Sign Up to Get Started
</center> </h2>      
      <p><center><Button style={{color:"white"}}onClick={SignUp}>

      Sign Up
      </Button></center></p>
      
      <p><center><Button style={{color:"white"}}onClick={SignIn}>

      Sign In
      </Button></center></p>
      </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('home'));
```

Everything is running but when I click on the SignUp button it doesn't redirect me to google.

Comment: Use an anchor with an `href` instead of a button with an `onClick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function SignUp(){
   window.location.href = "https://google.com";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `SignUp` function, you need to redirect user to a new url by assigning `window.location.href`:

```js
function SignUp() {
   window.location.href = "https://google.com";
}
```

Or if you prefer to open the link in a new window:

```js
function SignUp() {
   window.open("https://google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to learn about HTML/CSS/JS first, then try React.

You are trying to use `<link>` tag as `<a>`, which is totally incorrect. You can replace `<Button` tag with code below:

```
<a style={{color:"white"}} href="https://google.com">
  Sign Up
</a>
```